# Pyinfra Forwarding SSH Agent

Tags: ssh, pyinfra

I'm using `pyinfra` to run some script on server X that rsyncs some files from server Y. However I'm getting a `Permission denied (publickey).` error as the public key of X is not on Y.

Is there a way to forward my ssh key to server X so that it can use it to connect to server Y? (Basically, is it possible to do run commands with something like `ssh -A` with `pyinfra`?)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Did I try what? I read the documentation and the source code and it seems like the only way to do this is to set the `ForwardAgent` in `~/.ssh/config`. For some reason this works if I run `pyinfra` from my local but does not work when run in a CI pipeline.

Comment: Hi @giuppep - that's correct about setting `ForwardAgent` in the SSH config - I'm using this succesfully on a Jenkins server as well so this should be possible to achieve. What CI pipeline are you using?

Comment: Another question - does `ssh -A` work within the CI pipeline?

EDIT: I've added an issue that would enable explicitly setting this via the connector (although would still like to resolve this via SSH config if possible): https://github.com/Fizzadar/pyinfra/issues/598.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm using gitlab CI. Good point on checking whether `ssh -A` works at all in the CI pipeline. I'll try to have a look tomorrow.